# SDL Net2 Missing TCP packets

Tags: c++, sdl

I am using SDL and [Net2 lib](https://web.archive.org/web/20130608150018/http://www.gameprogrammer.com/net2/net2-0.html) for a client-server application.

The problem I am facing is that I am not receiving all of my TCP packets from my client unless I place a delay before sending each packet from client.

Removing the delay I get only one packet.

Answer (score 3):

A TCP connection is a stream of bytes. Your client could send 20 packets of 5 bytes each, and the server read it as one 100-byte sequence. You'll need to split the data up yourself.

Comment: I did as you said and it does seem I am receiving all my data at once.

Comment: But I don't want this to happen can I disable this?

Comment: This is how TCP works. It doesn't know about logical packets, it's simply a series of transmitted bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're not guaranteed (in regular sockets) to receive all packets at one time, you may have to call your receive function more than once, to receive all data. This is of course depends on your definition of a "packet" are you receiving all of your data?

+1 erik

Comment: Yes I am receiving all of my data.Any suggestions on how I should declare my packets? I have come to realized that my packets are quite small and TCP bundles them together before sending them instead of sending each packet one at a time. I am sending my packets with a 'key' at the beginning, so that the server knows what to do with each packet but now that I see this is happening am not sure what I should do.

Comment: Well with your 'key' you could simply run through the received data and check for your key, or at the beginning of each packet you could send the exact amount of bytes for this message you're sending. Lots of options =)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not guaranteed to be reliable, you most likely want to use UDP, not TCP. Net2 handles UDP very well. UDP is actually very reliable. UDP is message oriented. UDP messages tend to get sent quickly and get special treatment by routers (not always a good thing :-). UDP is often used in games.

BTW, if you had asked this question on the SDL mailing list, or sent it to me directly, you would have gotten this advice many months ago.

I wrote Net2 and I hang out on the SDL list. I do not hang out here because this place is an infinite time sink.

Bob Pendleton